# Looking for a clarification of the Suslin $\mathcal{A}$-Operation with a (finite) example

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory, self-learning, descriptive-set-theory

I have a problem concerning the output of (and the intuition behind) the **Suslin $\mathcal{A}$-Operation**.

More specifically, I really don't see exactly what the output of it really is (even if I can actually use it to prove some very basic things), and I think this hampers my general understanding.

In order to get some intuition, I decided to translate everything in terms of finite sets (this one should be an instantiation of the Alexandroff Operation). By doing this, I also added some numbered questions to emphasise my problems.

This is the basic setting:

- $X = \{ a, b \}$
- $A = \{0, 1 \}$
- $A_e = \{ a, b \}$, $A_0 = \{ a \}$, $A_1 = \{ b \}$, $A_{00} = \varnothing = A_{10} = A_{01} = A_{11}$

where a Suslin scheme is a function of the form $A : A^{<\mathbb{N}} \to 2^X$.

So, we have that

$$ \mathcal{A}_2 ( \{ A_s \} ) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A^{\mathbb{N}}} \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{\alpha|n} \hspace{7cm} (\square),$$

where $\{ A_s \}$ denotes the family of all the $A$ sets previously considered (this is a Suslin scheme that is also regular), and $\alpha|n$ denotes the initial segment $\alpha = ( \alpha_0, \alpha_1 , \dots, \alpha_{n-1})$ of length $n$ of a $\alpha \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$. Hence we have that

$$x \in \mathcal{A}_2 ( \{ A_s \} ) \Longleftrightarrow \exists \alpha \in A^{\mathbb{N}} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ ( x \in A_{\alpha|n}) \hspace{3cm}(*).$$

Now, my problems start here.

***1.*** Does this actually means that in this case, with finite $X$, the $\mathcal{A}$-Operation gives an empty result?

This is my hypothesis because my intuition is the following. We are in a finite context, and no matter what $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we pick, still the process basically ends at the second digit (i.e. $A_{**}$) which is associated with the empty set, and hence there is no element that can fit the RHS of $(*)$.

***2.*** Is this line of reasoning correct?

If this is the case, then a natural consideration is that the power of the Suslin $\mathcal{A}$-Operation really comes from infinite spaces, where this process can go on indefinitely.

***3.*** Again, is this correct?

I am really looking forward to any feedback.

Thank you in advance for your time.

*PS: The notation I used should be rather standard in set theory, but I will clarify if needed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a Suslin scheme, you must have a set $A_\sigma$ for *each* $\sigma\in{^{<\omega}X}$; since you have only $A_\sigma$ for $|\sigma|\le 2$, you don’t have a Suslin scheme and cannot define the result of the $\mathscr{A}$-operation. If you set $A_\sigma=\varnothing$ for all $\sigma\in{^{<\omega}X}$ of length greater than $1$, so as to have a genuine Suslin scheme, then for each $\varphi\in{^\omega\omega}$ you have

$$\bigcap_{n\in\omega}A_{\varphi\upharpoonright n}=\varnothing\;,$$

since already $A_{\varphi\upharpoonright 2}=\varnothing$. Thus,

$$\bigcup_{\varphi\in{^\omega\omega}}\bigcap_{n\in\omega}A_{\varphi\upharpoonright n}=\varnothing$$

as well.

Comment: Yeah, one of these cases where less is actually less; and with only finitely many objects you don't get a meaningful example!

Comment: As always, (more than) thanks a lot for this (again as always) enlightening answer!

Comment: @Kolmin: My pleasure!